# Why is Color.HSBtoRGB() representing every color as if I put hue as 0, regardless of what number I put in?

Tags: java, colors

Every time I run the program, the color being returned is showing up as the red of a hue of 0, regardless of what is being as hue. The original color shows up perfectly fine, so it's something about the conversion from RGB to HSB and back again.

I am trying to create a color palette to show up on screen, and I am using user-input edited hue, saturation, and value, so I have to convert the RGB to HSB, make the edits, and change the HSB back to RGB. I have used sysout to make sure that that hue isn't just being converted to 0 or 360 somewhere in the process of calculation, so I'm pretty sure that the problem lies somewhere in what's happening in the changedColor line.

I have put in a float for hue between 0 and 1, and a float between 0 and 360, but neither have changed anything.

```
    public Color changingColor(Color color, Integer changeHue, Integer changeSat, Integer changeBright) {
        float[] tempHSB = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
        float h = tempHSB[0]+(float)changeHue;
        float s = tempHSB[1]+(float)changeSat/100;
        float b = tempHSB[2]+(float)changeBright/100;
        if (h > 360) {
            h = h - 360;
        } else if (h < 0) {
            h = 360 + h;
        }
        if (s > 1) {
            s = 1;
        } else if (s < 0) {
            s = 0;
        }
        if (b > 1) {
            b = 1;
        } else if (b < 0) {
            b = 0;
        }
        h = h/360;
        h = Math.round(h);
        Color changedColor = Color.HSBtoRGB(h, s, b);
        return changedColor;
    }
```

Comment: `Color.HSBtoRGB(h, s, b)` returns is returning an **int** data type not a **Color** type. Try `Color changedColor = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(h, s, b));` instead.

Comment: I believe you are also going beyond the float range for HSB (0.0 to 1.0) with your **tempHSB[*n*]** updates,

Comment: Provide the source for _Color_.  The Java _[Color](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html)_ does not have this method.  Or, is this an editing error?  The code will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was going outside of range in my hue. I've changed h to be divided by 360 in the beginning, and to be checked if it goes below or above 0 or 1.

```
public Color changingColor(Color color, Integer changeHue, Integer changeSat, Integer changeBright) {
        float[] tempHSB = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
        float h = tempHSB[0]+(float)changeHue/360;
        float s = tempHSB[1]+(float)changeSat/100;
        float b = tempHSB[2]+(float)changeBright/100;
        if (h > 1) {
            h = h - 1;
        } else if (h < 0) {
            h = 1 + h;
        }
        if (s > 1) {
            s = 1;
        } else if (s < 0) {
            s = 0;
        }
        if (b > 1) {
            b = 1;
        } else if (b < 0) {
            b = 0;
        }
        Color changedColor = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(h, s, b));
        return changedColor;
    }
```